# htaccess question mark to slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm trying to do this by using .htaccess

> https://xyzzz.com/country.php?id=157 >> https://xyzzz.com/country/57/

> https://xyzzz.com/tld.php?id=123 >> https://xyzzz.com/tld/123/

I try

```
RewriteRule ^country/([a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)$ country.php?id=$1
```

My understanding is limited, I just gave my best shot.
Is there any way for this, or I am just doing something which is impossible by htaccess... if possible please help.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rectangle/

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainsanalytics.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainsanalytics.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainsanalytics.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(country)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(tld)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

and this is the URL I am trying to make SEO freindly

https://domainsanalytics.com/country.php?id=219

Comment: Why do you have `RewriteBase /rectangle/` when `/rectangle` is not part of your URL?

Answer (score 1):

***Generic Rule:*** Could you please try following, written and tested based on your shown samples. Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

---

---

***Specific rules only for shown samples:*** Following are very specific to your shown samples only, please make sure you put either Generic OR these at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(country)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(tld)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: It actually working, but its ot redirecting tlds.php?id=123 to  tld/123/

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13 https://domainsanalytics.com/tlds.php?id=1063

Comment: @GraceJ., So you mean any url with query string`?.....` should be ignored by this rule? Am I right here? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: no, its not moving... if i type directly in the browser it works then only 

https://domainsanalytics.com/country.php?id=37

Comment: @GraceJ., could you please do let me know where are you facing issues in here, could try to help, thank you.